# Error during session start in phpmyadmin

Tags: wampserver

I'm using WampServer 3.0.6 64 bit. When I type localhost on my Google Chrome I'm getting error like this:

> Error during session start; please check your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly. Also ensure that cookies are enabled in your browser.
>
> session_start(): open(SESSION_FILE, O_RDWR)) failed: Invalid argument (22)

Even I removed all the cookies from my browser and restarted my WampServer and still getting the same error.

Comment: Upgrade to WAMPServer 3.1.0 Link for the [upgrdae can be found here](Wampserver update 3.1.0) This wont fix your problem but at least you will be on the latest version. This upgrade will not effect the versions of Apache/MySQL/PHP you are using, just the WAMPServer internals.

Comment: Then check your `session.save_path` in `php.ini` make sure it is pointing to the `wamp\tmp` folder. Use the wampmanager menus to open `php.ini` to make sure you are opening the correct file